# ndb.transaction_async() vs async calls inside a transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm in the process of moving my ndb codebase to async as much as possible where it makes sense. There is a scenario where I'm not quite sure how to proceed: transactions.

As I see it, I have 3 options available:

#### Option 1: Call `ndb.transaction()` synchronously, and have the transaction's function call async methods.

```py
def option_1():
    @ndb.tasklet
    def txn():
        e = yield Foo.get_by_id_async(some_id)
        if e is None:
            e = yield Foo().put_async()
        raise ndb.Return(e)

    # The doc for ndb.transaction() says that it takes a function or tasklet.
    # If it's a tasklet, does it wait on the Future that is returned?
    # If it doesn't wait, what is the proper way to call a tasklet in a transaction
    # and get access to its return value?
    return ndb.transaction(txn)
```

#### Option 2: Call `ndb.transaction()` asynchronously, and have the transaction's function call sync methods.

```py
@ndb.toplevel
def option_2():
    def txn():
        e = Foo.get_by_id(some_id)
        if e is None:
            e = Foo().put()
        return e

    result = yield ndb.transaction_async(txn)
    return result
```

#### Option 3: Call `ndb.transaction()` asynchronously, and have the transaction's function call async methods.

```py
@ndb.toplevel
def option_3():
    @ndb.tasklet
    def txn():
        e = yield Foo.get_by_id_async(some_id)
        if e is None:
            e = yield Foo().put_async()
        raise ndb.Return(e)

    result = yield ndb.transaction_async(txn)
    return result
```

I feel like option 3 is the one to go to, but I'd rather rely on an expert opinion/advice...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, #3 is definitely the way to go.  The other two have the problem that they mix async and sync code and that's generally not a good thing to do except at the very top level of your app.

PS. Indeed the transaction waits for the callback if it is a tasklet.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but from what I see in the source, all of the transaction/transactional functions in ndb/model.py ultimately end up at the transaction method of the Context class... which is itself marked as a @tasklet.  it would seem then that any code inside of a transaction would need to be async, else it would be mixing sync/async code, yes?  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/context.py#L946